# Step function and unit sphere, who's no a sequentially compact space

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, normed-spaces, step-function

I've been asked following question.

The closed unit sphere is not a sequentially compact space. We define the closed unit sphere as $K := \{ f\in T[a,b] \mid \| f \|_\infty \leq 1 \}$

whereas $T[a,b]$ is the set of all step functions of $[a,b] \subset \mathbb{R}$ and $\| f \|_\infty = \sup\{|f(x)|: x\in [a,b]\}$

---

So I need to find a sequence $(f_n) \subset K$ which has no convergent subsequence that has a limit in K, if I'm correct.

I thought about this problem a lot and I came up with this solution....

$f_n(x) := \begin{cases}1 & \text{for} \quad x=b \\ \frac{1}{r} &\text{for}  \quad \frac{b-a}{r}+a\leq x < \frac{b-a}{r-1}+a \quad \text{with} \quad r\in\{2,...,n\}\\0 & \text{for} \quad x=a\end{cases}$

Explanation: $(f_n)$ is obviously a step function in [a,b] and $\|f_n\|\leq 1$. But the limit function $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f_n$ is not a step function since it has infinitely many pieces.

Because the limit of the sequence converges to $f_\infty$, all subsequences converge to $f_\infty$. Therefore no subsequence is in K and therefore K is not a sequentially compact space.

---

Is that correct or am I entirely on the wrong track? Thanks for helpful answers!

Comment: $\lim f_n(x)=0$ for $x<b$ and $1$ for $x=b$. So the limit function is  a step function.

Comment: What is a step function in this case?

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy You're right. I've edited my mistake. 1/n is now 1/r.

Comment: @user759562 what do you mean?

Comment: I'm asking for the definition of a step function. I always thought step functions were functions whose range contained two values, the preimages of which were intervals, but this is clearly not what is happening here. What definition are you using?

Comment: @Quotenbanane You will have to prove the existence of $\lim f_n$ w.r.t. the norm you have defined.

Comment: @user759562 a step function $f\in T[a,b]$ is a step function, if there are $a=t_0<t_1<...<t_n=b$ and $f(x)=c_j  \quad \forall x \in (t_{j-1},t_j)$ with $c_j$ is a constant value.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy How can I do that?

Comment: If I were you @Quotenbanane, I would try finding an infinite discrete subspace. Find an infinite family of distinct intervals $\{I_n\}$, and consider the indicator functions on these intervals. They should each be in $K$, and be distance $1$ from each other. It shouldn't be difficult to see that no subsequence could even be Cauchy, let alone convergent.

Comment: @user759562 I see what you mean but isn't it kind of the same thing as what I'm doing here? Defining a function on K, then let the intervalls go infinitely small and thus proving that $f_\infty$ is not a step function/convergent in K? You're proving that there is no convergent subsequence, am I right? But I'm proving that $f_\infty$ is not a step function because a step function can only have finitely many intervalls/function-values.

Comment: @user759562 Sorry, if my comment seems unfriendly. I'm just curious!

Comment: @Quotenbanane Not at all! I didn't get that impression. I would say that we are approaching the question in different ways. What I like more about my approach (which is indeed finding a sequence with no convergent subsequence) over your approach is that mine takes place purely within the space of step functions. You try to construct a sequence which does not converge within the space, which is only sensible if you consider the space of step functions as a subspace of a larger space. It's still valid to do this, but the subsequence approach is conceptually cleaner.

Comment: I understand. It is really a lot cleaner if I stay in the space of step function. Thanks for adding a new perspective to this problem. I'll try to construct what you've advised. I'll get back to you if I succeed!